# Get cache entries(keys, values) list on particular node in Apache ignite

Tags: gridgain, ignite

Is there any option in **ignitevisorcmd** where I can see what entries(key,value details) are present in particular node? I tried **cache -scan -c=mycache -id8=12345678** command but it prints entries from all other nodes also for mycache instead of printing data for **12345678** node only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current version of Visor Cmd does not support this, but I think it is easy to implement. I created [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4043) in Ignite JIRA, you may track or even contribute.

Comment: Hi, @kuaw26 I want to contribute to this issue. How can I do this? Can you please guide me.

Comment: Yes, you can. Please refer to https://ignite.apache.org/community/contribute.html#contribute